# What COM support is needed to get my custom DirectShow filter property page to work for a remote filter from the Running Object Table

Tags: com, directshow

I have some custom DirectShow filters with custom property pages. These work fine when the filter is in the same process as the property page.

However when I use the 'connect to remote graph' feature of Graph Edit the property pages don't work. 
When the property page does a QueryInterface for my private COM interface on the remote filter, the QueryInterface fails. Property pages of Microsoft filters (e.g. the EVR video renderer) work fine so it must be possible.

Presumably this is happening because my filter's private interfaces only work 'in process' and I need to add extra COM support so that these interfaces will work with an 'out of process' filter. What do I need to do in COM terms to achieve this?

Do the DirectShow baseclasses support these COM features? Can I reliably detect when the filter is running out of process and refuse to show the property page gracefully?

Comment: further debugging - QueryInterface on a remote graph filter works for the standard Microsoft interface ISpecifyPropertyPages so it's my own private COM interface that seems to be the problem.

Comment: You'll need to build and register the proxy/stub for your COM interface so it can be marshaled across process boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That all makes sense. Is there any reason I can't build the proxy/stub support code generated by MIDL into the same DLL that implements the COM server?

Comment: No great reason, other than that you don't always care to have the whole DLL loaded if the process only needs the proxy.  Building it separately is boilerplate and least likely to cause build problems.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to build a proxy/stub pair. But another, and way easier, is to make your private interface automation compatible (derive from `IDispatch`, type constranits apply), and put it into type library, which is to be attached to the DLL, and registered the usual way. Proxy/stub pair will be supplied for such interface automatically without need to bother.

DirectShow base classes do not offer built in support for this. Stock DirectShow filters provided with Windows might be not not be compatible with passing interfaces over process boundaries and my guess would be that it depends on the team in charge for respective development years ago. Video renderers, for instance, have interfaces that you can connect remotely through. Audio renderers, on the contrary, have interfaces without such capability in mind and they just crash one of the processes attempting to makes such connection (client side process, if my memory serves me right).